# Is there a way to use min.js file into a react project? Is it a good practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I have a min.js file that has a functionality that I want to use in my react project. However, I haven't found a way to use it. I don't know where to place that file, how to import it in my react project and finally use a function in that file. Apparently, the creator has not made it available via npm yet. Also, is it a good practice to use the file in the react project?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your react project

- public\index.html

```html
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <main id="container"></main>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
```

Add the used `min.js` like above would be fine.

---

It will be requested when you start your page, like the below example.

[image]